# how to use window onunload event in backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-views

I am fairly new to backbone and I wanted to use window onunload event with one of my view. 
Actually I have created a view for my html page and I want to call some function at the unload of that page. This page is loaded inside a iframe or in a window.open and hence when the window is closed I want to call a function.
But the event doesnt fire when I write

```
  events: {
          "beforeunload window": "myalert"
      }
```

or

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", myalert);
```

I saw some threads saying we should use route for this purpose but didn't got some good guide for it. Some suggestions/help will be appriciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution between numerous solution is to have your view listen to an event that your window will trigger, here's an example:

In your view:

```
Backbone.Events.once('windowClosed', myalert');
window.open('your new window url here');
```

And in the new window, when you want to close it:

```
$(window).on("unload", function() {
    window.opener.Backbone.Events.trigger('windowClosed');
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I cannot call the window.close explicitly, the user will click on the redcross button on the topright of the window/close the tab by himself. I have to call my function before the page is unloaded/closed.

Comment: Just use `$(window).on("unload", myalert);` where `myalert` should be a function which has to return a string with message for confirm leaving the page.

Comment: Thanks @RidaBENHAMMANE and Eugene. I tried this but its not working, maybe I am doing it wrong. Lemme try to explain once again what I m trying to do in simpler manner. Suppose I have a simple app  xyz.html which uses require and backbone. This xyz.html is opened in a window.open and I want to call one function myalert when this xyz.html closes.

Comment: @swapnil0545 where is your function? In xyz.html or in the window that open it?

Comment: @RidaBENHAMMANE Sorry, writing the $(window).on("unload", myFunc); inside boardview.js used in xyz.html worked for me. But can't we assign the window event to handlers in view events?